# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Do I have to deploy my app with full "/node_modules" and "/bower_components" and compiled sass and other dependencies?

Tags: node.js, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I don't understand the way AWS Elastic Beanstalk work in terms of Node.js app. Best practices of Node.js development say that one don't have to push `/node_modules` or `/bower_components` or other third party packages to version control systems (GitHub, for example), only `package.json`. All those `/node_modules` have to be in `.gitignore`. Then any person can do `npm install` or `bower install` and install all the dependencies. And the same is for `sass` - compile them for production env.

Ok, but what about AWS Elastic Beanstalk? How do I have to create a source bundle of my Node.js app? Do I have to commit FULL `/node_modules` and `/bower_components` and then make a `.zip` bundle with them? But my HEAD commit is without `/node_modules`, because `/node_modules` is in `.gitignore`. So no dependencies will be in `.zip` bundle:

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD > app.zip
```

Or do I have an option to install all the dependencies AFTER I have deployed my `app.zip` to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Or AWS Elastic Beanstalk does `npm install` by itself somewhere under the hood immediately after I have uploaded my `app.zip` bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Elastic Beanstalk runs a few npm commands when deploying your app using got. I did a [little experiment](http://clarkie.io/nodejs/2015/06/25/npm-scripts-on-elastic-beanstalk.html) a few months back.

In short, you can use `npm install` to deploy your dependencies, then use `npm prestart` to build and compile things like sass.